# R: A function to tell whether a single char is vowel or not

Tags: r, function, logical-operators

I'm dealing with `if` in R and I'm struggling with one of the typical examples: checking if it is a vowel= TRUE and FALSE otherwise.

```
if.function <- function(char){
  if (char=('a') or ('e') or ('i') or ('o') or ('u') ) 
    {
    return(TRUE)
  } else if (char == 0){
    return(FALSE)
  }
```

Could someone give me a hand?

I saw other examples with Python and Java, but I barely know how to use just R.

Comment: Using `%in%` is the canonical R method (see `help("%in%")` for examples). To translate the logic into a "standard" logical statement, use `if (char==('a') ||  char==('e') || char==('i') || char==('o') || char==('u') )`. You can see why `%in%` is preferred.

Comment: `grepl(char, '[aeiou]')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`char=('a') or ('e') or ('i') or ('o') or ('u')` is illegal. Try

```
isVowel <- function(char) char %in% c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

Let's try it:

```
isVowel('a')
# [1] TRUE
isVowel('b')
# [1] FALSE
```

---

Note that I did not use the or operator `'||'`:

```
char == 'a' || char == 'e' || char == 'i' || char == 'o' || char == 'u'
```

as this is too long. I have used

```
char %in% c('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

This will give `TRUE` if `char` is any of `'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'`.